# I get this error TS2554: Expected 3-4 arguments, but got 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, gsap

I am using gsap plugin to create a text animation.
In the last line of code of my function 'animation_text_1',
where it says "TweenMax.staggerFromTo(.....)", I get this error:
error TS2554: Expected 3-4 arguments, but got 5
Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      animation_text_1("#text-anim");
    });

    function animation_text_1 (element:any){
      let i:any;
      var newText = "";
      var theText = document.querySelector(element);
      for (i = 0; i < theText.innerText.length; i++) {
        newText += "<div>";
        if (theText.innerText[i] == " "){newText += "&nbsp;"}
        else {newText += theText.innerText[i];}
        newText += "</div>";
      }
      theText.innerHTML = newText;
      var targetsDiv = document.querySelectorAll(element+" div");
      TweenMax.staggerFromTo(targetsDiv, 2, {opacity:0, y:90, ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1.2, 0.5)}, {opacity:1, y:0, ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1.2, 0.5)}, 0.03);  

    }
```

Any advice to solve this problem will be helpfull!!

Comment: There's no need for TweenMax. Use GSAP 3 and the modern syntax: https://greensock.com/mistakes/

Answer (score 0):

The `TweenMax.staggerFromTo` take 3 OR 4 params you used 5 params in your code; check [here](https://greensock.com/docs/v2/TimelineMax/staggerFromTo()) try change it to:

```
  TweenMax.staggerFromTo(targetsDiv, 2, {opacity:0, y:90, ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1.2, 0.5)}, {opacity:1, y:0, ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1.2, 0.5)});
```

**UPDATE**

I just realized it will be a mismatch of versions. the v2 (that you probably using) has `staggerFromTo` function that takes 3 or 4 params.

The new version v3 (your code implementation) has `staggerFromTo` function that takes 5. You can fix the issue simply by migrating to the newer version

`npm install gsap@3.7.0`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abderrahim. I did what you said and it compiled the project pretty well since I am using Angular 12; but the animation does not seem to work like it does in this codepen link: https://codepen.io/Tiopayo/pen/abOOaQb, I might be missing something.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroLópezdeAnda Please check my answer updates